# Given groups=1, weight of size [], expected input[] to have channels, but got channels insteadの解決を手伝っていただけないでしょうか？

Tags: python, pytorch

PytorchでAIモデルを構築中です。
畳み込み層を作成中に以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-277e33b168b8> in <module>
    767 
    768 if __name__== '__main__':
--> 769   run()

9 frames
<ipython-input-42-277e33b168b8> in run()
    763      scaling=False,
    764      overfitting=False,
--> 765      train_counts=6)
    766 
    767 

<ipython-input-42-277e33b168b8> in main(gpu_id, lr, num_epochs, batch_size, weight_decay, pretrained_model, pretrained_type, start_idx, end_idx, freeze_layer, output_dir, early_stopping, downscale_median, scaling, augmentation, overfitting, train_counts)
    564                               loss_type='MSE&Cosine',
    565                               corr_w=corr_w,
--> 566                               score_metric="spearmanr")
    567 
    568 

<ipython-input-34-85643d1c012f> in val(val_loader, model, use_gpu_number, criterion, loss_type, corr_w, score_metric, mean_outputs)
     20           time_course = Variable(time_course.cuda(use_gpu_number)).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
     21 
---> 22           output = model(track)
     23 
     24           if loss_type == 'RMSE':

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-28-c1073582f8a6> in forward(self, input)
    187             if model_number != self.train_counts*-2-1:
    188                 t_out = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')(t_out)
--> 189             l_out = self.cnn[model_number+1](out_list[out_number])
    190             t_out = transforms.CenterCrop([l_out.shape[2], l_out.shape[3]])(t_out)
    191             out = torch.cat((t_out, l_out), 1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    137     def forward(self, input):
    138         for module in self:
--> 139             input = module(input)
    140         return input
    141 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    455 
    456     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 457         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    458 
    459 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    452                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    453         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 454                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    455 
    456     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 32, 3, 3], expected input[32, 256, 10, 256] to have 32 channels, but got 256 channels instead
```

現在作成しているのはTDMという脳内の処理を模倣したAIの実装です。
恐らくエラーが出ているのは、L_0というレイヤーだと思います。
しかしこのレイヤーは lateral layerと言って、入力と出力のチャンネル数が等しくないといけません。
元になっている資料は以下のものです。
https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1612.06851/

それも考慮すると、どう対処していいのかわからず質問させていただきました。
書いたコードは以下の通りです。

```
from pandas.core.api import to_datetime
from operator import ifloordiv
from torchvision import transforms


class CRNN_VGG_BN_3FC_MaxPool(nn.Module):
    """
    Adapted from Choi, 2017 and Malik, 2017
    """
    def __init__(self, weight_init=False,
                 verbose=False,
                 gpu_id=0,
                 cnc=[32, 64, 128 ,128,256,256,512],
                 transfer=False,
                 train_counts=6):
      
        super(CRNN_VGG_BN_3FC_MaxPool, self).__init__()
        pooling = [(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2,2), (2,2), (2,4),(4,4)]
        kernel_size = (2, 2)
        conv_num_channels = cnc
        num_conv = 7

        self.verbose = verbose
        self.train_counts = train_counts

        # cnn construction
        cnn = nn.Sequential()
        cnn.add_module("BN" + str(0), 
                       nn.BatchNorm2d(1))
        for i in range(num_conv):

          if i == 0:
                prev_out_channels = 1

          else:
            prev_out_channels = conv_num_channels[i - 1]

          cnn.add_module("Conv" + str(i), 
                         self.conv_elu(i, prev_out_channels, conv_num_channels[i])) 
          cnn.add_module("MaxPooling" + str(i), 
                         nn.MaxPool2d(pooling[i],
                                      stride=(2,2)))
          
        self.cnn = cnn
     

        # ====================================================
        # ====================== TDM =========================
        # ====================================================

        tdm = nn.Sequential()

        t_dim_list = [(512, 512), (768, 384), (640, 384), (512, 128),(256,64),(128,32)]
        l_dim_list = [(256, 256), (256, 256), (128, 128), (128, 128),(64,64),(32,32)]
        model_number_list = [5,4,3, 2, 1, 0]
        # ============= Add TDM =============
        for i in range(self.train_counts):
          model_number = model_number_list[i]
            # ============ Make T Layer ============
          block = nn.Sequential()
          block.add_module('Conv_T', nn.Conv2d(t_dim_list[i][0],
                                               t_dim_list[i][1],
                                               kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                               stride=1,
                                               padding=1))
          
          block.add_module('ReLU_T', nn.ReLU())
          tdm.add_module(f'T_{model_number+1},{model_number}', block)
            # ============ Make L Layer ============
          block = nn.Sequential()
          block.add_module('Conv_L', nn.Conv2d(l_dim_list[i][0],
                                             l_dim_list[i][1],
                                             kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                             stride=1,
                                             padding=1))
          block.add_module('ReLU_L', nn.ReLU())
          tdm.add_module(f'L_{model_number}', block)

          
        ##################
        ########.  T_out layerをここに追加してしまおう

        block = nn.Sequential()
        block.add_module('Conv_T_out', 
                         nn.Conv2d(64,
                                   512,
                                   kernel_size=(3,3)))
        block.add_module('ReLU_T_out', nn.ReLU())
        tdm.add_module('T_out_0', block)
        

        self.tdm = tdm



        self.AdaptiveMaxPool2d = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((1, 16)) 
        self.AdaptiveAvgPool2d = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 16))

        # rnn construction
        self.rnn_nHidden = 64
        self.rnn_nLayer = 2
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=512,
                           hidden_size=self.rnn_nHidden,
                           num_layers=self.rnn_nLayer,
                           dropout=0.75,
                           bidirectional=True)
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(TimeDistributed(nn.Linear(self.rnn_nHidden * 2, self.rnn_nHidden)),
                                    nn.BatchNorm1d(16),
                                    nn.ELU(), #Expotential Linear Unit
                                    nn.Dropout(0.5),
                                    TimeDistributed(nn.Linear(self.rnn_nHidden, int(self.rnn_nHidden/2))),
                                    nn.BatchNorm1d(16),
                                    nn.ELU(),
                                    nn.Dropout(0.1),
                                    nn.Linear(int(self.rnn_nHidden/2), 1))
        self.gpu_id = gpu_id
        if weight_init:
            self.cnn.apply(self.weight_init)
            self.linear.apply(self.weight_init)

   

    def conv_elu(self, i, in_channels, out_channels):
        """
        Convolution Block consists of Conv2d + BatchNorm + Elu
        """
        block = nn.Sequential()
        if i >0:
            for j in range(3):
                if j < 2:
                    block.add_module("Conv_{}_{}".format(i, j), nn.Conv2d(in_channels,
                                                                in_channels,
                                                                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                                                stride=1,
                                                                padding=1))
                    block.add_module("ELU_{}_{}".format(i, j), nn.ELU())
                else:
                    block.add_module("Conv_{}_{}".format(i, j), nn.Conv2d(in_channels,
                                                                          out_channels,
                                                                          kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                                                          stride=1,
                                                                          padding=1))
                    block.add_module("BN_{}_{}".format(i, j), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
                    block.add_module("ELU_{}_{}".format(i, j), nn.ELU())
        else:
            block.add_module("Conv_{}".format(i), nn.Conv2d(in_channels,
                                                              out_channels,
                                                              kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                                              stride=1,
                                                              padding=1))
            block.add_module("BN_{}".format(i), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
            block.add_module("ELU_{}".format(i), nn.ELU())
        return block

    def weight_init(self, m):
        """
        Kaiming He Weight init
        """
        if isinstance(m, (nn.Conv2d, nn.Linear)):
          nn.init.kaiming_normal(m.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu') 
        elif isinstance(m, (nn.BatchNorm2d, nn.BatchNorm1d)):
            nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1) 
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

    def forward(self, input):
        # =========== CNN Forward ============
        conv = self.cnn.BN0(input)
        conv0 = self.cnn.Conv0(conv)
        conv0 = self.cnn.MaxPooling0(conv0)
        conv1 = self.cnn.Conv1(conv0)
        #conv1 = self.cnn.MaxPooling1(conv1)
        conv2 = self.cnn.Conv2(conv1)
        conv2 = self.cnn.MaxPooling2(conv2)
        conv3 = self.cnn.Conv3(conv2)
        #conv3 = self.cnn.MaxPooling3(conv3)
        conv4 = self.cnn.Conv4(conv3)
        conv4 = self.cnn.MaxPooling4(conv4)
        conv5 = self.cnn.Conv5(conv4)
        #conv5 = self.cnn.MaxPooling5(conv5)
        out = self.cnn.Conv6(conv5)
        # ============ T, L Layer Forward ============
        out_list = [conv5,conv4,conv3, conv2, conv1, conv0]
        for model_number, out_number in zip(range((self.train_counts*-2)-1, -1, 2), range(4)):
            t_out = self.cnn[model_number](out)
            if model_number != self.train_counts*-2-1:          
                t_out = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')(t_out) 
            l_out = self.cnn[model_number+1](out_list[out_number])
            t_out = transforms.CenterCrop([l_out.shape[2], l_out.shape[3]])(t_out)
            out = torch.cat((t_out, l_out), 1)

        # ============ T out Layer Forward ============
        if self.train_counts > 0:
            out = self.cnn[-1](out)
        # =========== Pooling ============
        if self.train_counts == 0 or self.train_counts == 1:
            out = self.cnn.MaxPooling4(out)
        else:
            out = self.AdaptiveMaxPool2d(out)

        # =========== Reshape ============
        b, c, h, w = out.size()
        out = out.view(b, c, -1)
        conv = out.permute(2, 0, 1) 
        # ============ RNN ===========
        rnn, hidden = self.rnn(conv)
        rnn = rnn.permute(1, 0, 2)
        # =========== linear regression ===========
        output = self.linear(rnn)
        # =========== Reshape ===========
        b, c, w = output.size()
        output = output.view(b, -1)

        return output
```

Comment: 質問記事に書かれているくらいの内容だと、たまたま同じようなプログラムに関わっている人が、このサイトを覗いていないと分からない感じでは？ 基にしたり参考にしている資料やプログラムなどへのリンクとか貴方が原因らしいと判断した根拠となる仕様の資料や公開可能な限りのやろうとしていることの仕組み等を追記してみてください。それからエラーメッセージは本当にその1行だけですか？ もっと色々と表示されていると思われるので略さず全てを記述してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
編集いたしました。ご確認いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

時間も経過しており既に解決済みかもしれませんが御参考です。
参考資料の TDM(Top-Down Modulation) のブロック図（Figure 2）を参照しながらコードを拝見すると，C層（ボトムアップパス）の計算は `self.cnn` が担当し，L層（ラテラルパス）と T層（トップダウンパス）の計算は `self.tdm` が担当すると読み取れます。
一方，エラーとなっている `l_out = self.cnn[model_number+1](out_list[out_number])` は L層の計算をしているにもかかわらず `self.cnn` が使われています。そこで，`t_out = self.cnn[model_number](out)` も合わせて `self.cnn` を `self.tdm` に置き換えたところ for ループではエラーは発生しなくなりました。
次に，出力前の `RNN` ブロックの `rnn, hidden = self.rnn(conv)` でもチャンネル不整合のエラーが発生するので，`self.rnn` の構築部分の `self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=512,` を `self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=256` に変更しました。
提示されたコードに上記の3カ所の変更を行い，先頭に

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from pytorch_forecasting.models.temporal_fusion_transformer.sub_modules import TimeDistributed
```

を追加をしたものを「tdm_module.py」に保存し，下記の記述例を実行した場合の出力（32行16列）の一部を示します。

```
import torch
import tdm_module

torch.manual_seed(11)

model = tdm_module.CRNN_VGG_BN_3FC_MaxPool()

x = torch.randn(32, 1, 10 * 8, 256 * 8)
print(model(x))
```

```
tensor([[-8.8882e-02, -3.1479e-01,  1.3590e-01, -6.0990e-02, -1.1239e-01,
         -3.5339e-02, -1.2717e-01, -8.5867e-02, -7.9190e-01,  7.5079e-01,
          2.9482e-02,  8.2766e-02, -8.2027e-02, -4.4313e-01,  8.1381e-02,
         -3.9718e-01],
        [-4.8103e-02,  5.8515e-02, -3.8677e-01,  1.5168e-01,  3.2936e-01,
          2.8742e-01,  2.9059e-01,  2.2381e-01, -9.4020e-01, -4.1080e-01,
         -5.9306e-02, -1.7687e-01,  1.8825e-01,  6.2861e-02,  5.9015e-01,
         -1.4683e-01],
         ...
        [-1.5363e-02, -4.0786e-01, -5.7508e-01, -5.1503e-01, -3.4224e-01,
         -1.3823e-01, -8.9653e-01, -3.1752e-01, -2.9232e-02, -1.1686e-02,
          2.2664e-01,  2.8617e-01, -2.3849e-01, -3.7007e-02,  3.3500e-02,
         -2.8974e-01],
        [-4.9130e-01, -2.0382e-01,  1.2202e-01, -4.5300e-01,  6.2589e-03,
          5.9880e-02,  1.7218e-01, -2.0273e-01, -5.3178e-01, -3.7083e-01,
         -2.0129e-01, -3.6231e-01,  3.2738e-01,  2.0378e-01, -6.2566e-02,
         -4.6619e-01]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>)
```